# How to send uploaded Image as parameter in c# to sql

Tags: c#

Here is my code. Error message was

> parameter  @event_image was not supplied

How to send image name as parameter? If I keep breakpoint it's not even entering into `If(fileupload1.HasFile)`.

I have to store the image in folder and the path must be stored into sql db

```
{
        conn.Open();
        string postdate = txtpostdate.Text;
        string unpostdate = txtunpostdate.Text;
        string name = txtname.Text;
        string description = txtdescription.Text;
        string country = dropcountry.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string multidate = txtstartdae.Text;
        string startend = dropstarttime.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string drop1m = dropti1m.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string dropme1h = droptimeend1h.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string drop2m = droptime2m.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string notes = txtnotes.Text;
        string prevlocation = droplocation.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string locationname = txtslocname.Text;
        string addres1 = txtsLocAddress1.Text;
        string addres2 = txtsLocAddress2.Text;
        string city = txtsLocCity.Text;
        string state = dropstate.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string zipcode = txtsLocZip.Text;
        string phonenumber = txtsLocPhone.Text;
        string faxnumber = txtsLocFax.Text;
        string notes2 = textnotes2.Text;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertEvents", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into pa_events(event_postdate,event_unpostdate,event_canvisitorsregisters,event_eventname,event_description,event_image,event_multydateevent,event_startdate,event_enddate,event_start,event_end,event_notes,location_name,location_addres1,location_addres2,location_cites,location_state,location_zipcode,location_phonenumber,location_faxnumber,location_notes,event_country) values(@event_postdate,@event_unpostdate,@event_canvisitorsregisters,@event_eventname,@event_description,@event_image,@event_multydateevent,@event_startdate,@event_enddate,@event_start,@event_end,@event_notes,@location_name,@location_addres1,@location_addres2,@location_cites,@location_state,@location_zipcode,@location_phonenumber,@location_faxnumber,@location_notes,@event_country)", conn);

        if (fileupload1.HasFile)
        {
            imagename = fileupload1.FileName;

            int length = fileupload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            fileupload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~\\images\\" + imagename));

             s = "~\\images\\" + imagename + "";
        }              


            if (radioyes.Checked == false && !radiono.Checked == false)
            {
                lblmsg.Text = "Please Select canve Register Yes! or No!";
            }

            if (radioyes.Checked == true)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_canvisitorsregisters", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Y";
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_canvisitorsregisters", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "N";
            }


            if (radiomultyyes.Checked == true)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_multydateevent", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Y";
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_multydateevent", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "N";
            }

            **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_image", s);**
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_postdate", postdate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_unpostdate", unpostdate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_eventname", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_description", description);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_country", country);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_startdate", startend);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_enddate", drop1m);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_start", dropme1h);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_end", drop2m);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_notes", notes);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location_name", locationname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location_addres1", addres1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location_addres2", addres2);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location_cites", city);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location_state", state);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location_zipcode", zipcode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location_phonenumber", phonenumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location_faxnumber", faxnumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location_notes", notes2);
            //if (fileupload1.PostedFile != null && fileupload1.PostedFile.FileName != "")
            //
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (i != 0)
            {
                lblmsg.Text = "record is inserted";
            }
            else
            {
                lblmsg.Text = "record is not inserted";
            }
            conn.Close();    
    }
```

Comment: How are you storing the image? What's the datatype in the database

Comment: where is the code that declares and populates fileupload1?

Comment: I am storing only path,varchar

Comment: if (fileupload1.HasFile)
        {
            imagename = fileupload1.FileName;

            int length = fileupload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            fileupload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~\\images\\" + imagename));

             s = "~\\images\\" + imagename + "";
        }

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_image", s);

Comment: even it would sound obvious, it seems that you're not uploading the file correctly, that's why it doesn't enter to the `If(fileupload1.HasFile)` because there is no file.... Check how you're uploading the file. Controller, Form, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't with your SQL insert, it's with however your file upload is set up.  You're getting that error because, as you stated, you're not even entering the if statement that creates the SQL parameter.

Could you post code related to the image upload? That's your root issue.

Comment: <p>
            <label for="image">
                Image:
            </label>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fileimage" runat="server" /></p>
        <p>

Comment: "fileimage" isn't the same name as "fileupload1" you're using above, but I'm guessing it's probably not that simple.  Where are you trying to access this image? You might be doing something with the Postback that's clearing it.

Comment: if the id is fileimage it should be `fileimage.HasFile` not `fileupload1.HasFile`....err it's complicated with so little code showed, `fileupload1.HasFile` I think would give you a compilation error

Answer (score 0):

honestly your code is  not clear but hope it works with you:
add parameter with file upload

```
if (fileupload1.HasFile)
    {
        imagename = fileupload1.FileName;

        int length = fileupload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        fileupload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~\\images\\" + imagename));

         s = "~\\images\\" + imagename + "";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_image", s);
   }
```